# How do I make a high signal last longer so my nodeMCU/Tasmota sees it?

Tags: capacitor, nodemcu, photoresistor

**Problem**
I have a data input signal to a nodeMCU running Tasmota. It only works intermittently because the signal often isn't high long enough for Tasmota to sense it. So I need to find a way to make the signal high last longer.

**Background**
My apartment block has a 12VAC doorbell system, wired into my apartment intercom. I want to be notified when the street bell button is pressed. My solution is to wire the 12VAC into a short LED strip, adjacent to which is a photoresistor wired to an input pin on a nodeMCU running Tasmota. This works OK, but only if the bell button is pressed for longer than a second or two. If the button is pressed briefly, the LED strip lights, but Tasmota doesn't detect the brief signal high.

I am looking for a way in which the duration of the high signal can be prolonged (say from 500ms to 2000ms) so Tasmota doesn't miss it.

Comment: useful search term : monostable

Comment: On the original system are you saying you can't hear something like the bell i.e. what is the problem with the original system that you think might be solved with your nodeMCU?

Comment: Here's your problem: "photoresistor"  Use a photodiode or phototransistor.

Comment: Or an optocoupler.

Comment: Probably more to the point: Use an optocoupler connected to the signal that powers the LED strip.

Comment: There may indeed be issues with this improvised optocoipler.  But if the signal gets through it at all, software using **interrupts** should be aware of it.  You could also look up various "pulse stretcher" solutions but those are inferrior to fixing the software.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think my problem is that I am using an analog port to detect the signal from the photoresistor, therefore I suspect the software that I am using (Tasmota) is polling rather than listening on an interrupt. I will look into changing the circuit such that the signal is a binary high-low on a digital input, or look into the photodiode approach suggested by JRE

Comment: @Andyaka I want to be notified of a bell-push when I am away from the apartment so I can open the door remotely.

Comment: @JRE I think you may be right. I'll look into using a photodiode to create a digital signal instead of my current analog solution. Could I ask you to suggest an appropriate component.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, my problem stemmed from using an analog input signal linked to a Tasmota rule. Either Tasmota wasn't polling the input value quickly enough to detect the change, or the photoresistor wasn't reacting quickly enough to the brief surge of light.

I replaced my LED-strip/photoresistor with an optocoupler and it now works reliably on even the briefest of bell pushes.

Many thanks for those who pointed me in this direction.